# Angular IO (Angular 2) : Programmatically get validators on a FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm creating a component that takes a FormGroup and dynamically creates a form.
In this component i want to check whether the FormControl of a input is required or not. Is there a way I could programmatically get the validators on a FormControl? I know there is a setValidators method, shouldn't it be a getValidators also?

Comment: You can access the validators property of the `FormControl`. I believe it's in the `_validators` property.

Comment: Are you sure? I cant see that property, and even if I did find it is it legit to use it? Doesn't feel safe to use a "private" property defined by underscore.

Comment: Sorry I thought I commented on another question. I'm not sure if it's safe, but as far as I know it's the only way to check the validators at this point.

Comment: @Erex did you ever find out about this?

Comment: @Zlatko Nope, I ended up using my own class for my form and inputs that held a instance of a FormGroup and FormControl. I then used mye own classes for adding removing and keeping track of the validators